# Symfony 4 - dump() displays "null" for some fields instead of an object

Tags: symfony, profiler, dump

I have an array of Category objects got from database. A Category object is linked to a DefaultCategory which is linked to an Image.

I execute the following code:

```
dump($categories[0]->getDefaultCategory());             
dump($categories[0]->getDefaultCategory()->getImage());
```

I get the following dump into the Symfony profiler (some parts are simplified with ... ):

```
DefaultCategory {#952 ▼
    ...
    -image: null
}
```

and

```
Image {#1032 ▼
    -id: "fbf7f005-5c86-4db0-a9b3-93373885134f"
    ...
}
```

There is actually an image linked to this default category, **so is there any reason why it is marked as null in the first dump ?**

For information, the getImage() code from the DefaultCategory class is simply:

```
/**                               
 *                                
 */                               
public function getImage() : Image
{                                 
    return $this->image;          
}
```

The profiler shows zero invalid entities.

Comment: It's probably due to Doctrine's lazy loading.  The dump command uses reflection to directly access your entities properties and thus will not trigger a lazy load.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your reply.